# Web frontend designer

Tags: django, web, frontend

I am trying to learn web development and I did take some Django courses. I would like to know is there some kind of "Frontend Designer" (some think similar to wordpress) that can create templates like html etc. which are easy to use for Django developer? Or are there some kind of "Frontend Designer" that are more optimized for Django?

Many many thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django as a backend for Apis and I would highly recommend using Frontend framework/Library like React/Vue.

I know you want an easy solution for frontend like WordPress (drag & drop ) but I don't think there is such a thing which you can customize with liberty and according to your ease and have your full control over it.

Plus, there are tons of themes and components available for React/Vue Or these libraries have a strong community.

Alternate,
You can use simple HTML with bootstrap, jquery.
They too have tons of themes available.